# React: useState Updated in Custom Hook's Async Function Not Reflected in Parent Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a React project and have created a custom hook to fetch data from an API. I've set the state within this hook as follows after retrieving the data:

```
const [realEstates, setRealEstates] = useState<RealEstate[]>([]);
...
const fetchRealEstates = useCallback(async (request: GetRealEstatesByCustomerNumberRequest) : Promise<void> => {
    try {
        setError(null);
        setLoading(true);
        const response : GetRealEstatesByCustomerNumberResponse = await post('./api/Estate/get-real-estates-by-customer-number', request);
        setRealEstates(response.RealEstates);
    } catch (error: any) {
        setError(error);
    }
    setLoading(false);
}, []);
...
```

I then use this custom hook in a component as shown below:

```
const { realEstates, fetchRealEstates } = useRealEstate();
...
const onCustomerSearchChangeValue = async (customer: any) => {
    dispatch(setSelectedCustomerNumber(customer.value.ExternalClientNo));
    await fetchRealEstates({ CustomerNumber: customer.value.ExternalClientNo });
    dispatch(setRealEstates(realEstates));
};
...
```

My problem is that I seem to be missing something, potentially related to the nature of JavaScript itself. When the **fetchRealEstates** hook is executed, it successfully retrieves data from the API and updates the state within the hook through **setRealEstates**. However, I observe that the state within the hook is not being updated as expected, leading to the component not receiving the correct value.

Additionally, when this operation is executed in a new event, I receive the values that I was trying to access in the previous iteration. This suggests to me that I might be missing something related to the asynchronous nature of the operation or the component lifecycle.

I understand that this process is asynchronous, and I'm guessing that the hook needs to be re-rendered in some way to see the new state value (though I'm a bit unclear on this part).

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

According to your post you want to get data and yet you are making a post request Instead of a get request and your fiction fetchRealEstates returns void

Try this approach

```
import { useState, useEffect } from `'react';`
import axios from 'axios';

const useFetchData = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        setData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  return { data, loading, error };
};

export default useFetchData;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I appreciate your attention to detail, but unfortunately, not every API is built ideally :) This POST request does return data. I can see there's no issue with it while debugging. Also, it doesn't matter that this function is void because I want to use the values I need through the state in my component. If you notice, there's also no return in my function.

Comment: I understand using useEffect to immediately reflect state changes within the hook, but I want to integrate multiple services into this custom hook. For example, I'm looking to add saveRealEstate. In this case, will I need to create separate useEffect and lifecycle definitions for each endpoint?

Comment: In React, the useEffect hook is typically used for handling side effects in functional components, such as fetching data from an API endpoint. If you have multiple API endpoints in your component and each requires different handling or has different lifecycle needs, you may need separate useEffect definitions, depending on the flow though

Comment: according to you fetchRealEstates function you use callback, perhabs you might want to add realEstates to the dependency array

Comment: I totally agree your solution, but I found what I need. Thanks for your helps!

Answer (score -1):

I recently encountered a challenge in my React application involving state synchronization between a custom hook and a Redux store. After some experimentation and research, I discovered an effective solution that I'd like to share, along with an explanation of why it works and what I had initially overlooked.

I implemented a useEffect hook in the parent component that listens for changes in the realEstates data from my custom hook and then dispatches an action to update the Redux store.

```
...
const { realEstates, fetchRealEstates } = useRealEstate();
...
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setRealEstates(realEstates));
}, [realEstates]);
...
const onCustomerSearchChangeValue = async (customer: any) => {
        dispatch(setSelectedCustomerNumber(customer.value.ExternalClientNo));
        await fetchRealEstates({ CustomerNumber: customer.value.ExternalClientNo });
    };
...
```

I hope this will work for you too.

Happy coding.